# Only getting every nth value of each row in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

So I have a .csv file with 35 columns, some of which I want to write to a database.

I only need about 4 of these columns - is it possible to just write say the 3rd value, the 25th value, and the 29th value in each row to a MySQL database?

Either that, or can I only write where the values are "Year", "Amount", and "Whatever"?

Now I know I could just truncate the Excel file, but its for a college assignment so I wanted to show a "techy" solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
desired_rows = [...]  # Rows you'd like to read, 0-based
for number, row in enumerate(reader):
    if not number in desired_rows:
        continue

    # Do stuff with the rows you want
    ....
```

Comment: No - I want to use values within each row. So for example, row 1 has Value1, Value2, Value3, ....... , Value34. What I want to do is only take Value4, Value9, Value24 for example and write these to my database for each row.

Comment: @user3600952 Once you're looping over the rows that you want to use, you can query for the columns you want by indexing the row: `row[3]` -- this will read the value in the fourth column in the current row. If you don't care about specific rows like your question indicates, you can just remove the `if` condition in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a function that would retrieve *all* of the elements from each row each time it's called.

Something like the following. Note I subtract `1` from each column because the first column is at row index `0`, the second at index `1`, etc.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

COLS = 3, 25, 29
filename = 'columns.csv'
getters = itemgetter(*(col-1 for col in COLS))

with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        print(getters(row))
```